# How to say something that will happen at X minutes every hour?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, time

I am coding a task scheduler. One of the options allows the user to select a task to be performed every hour at X minutes (ie. 00:45, 01:45, 02:45... 23:45).

Since I don't want to clutter the UI, I would like to know a short way of expressing this.

Assuming the user wants the task to be performed every hour at 45, these are the ways I have thought about, but they all sound weird to me.

> - Perform at 45 minutes (hourly)
> - Perform every 1 hour at minute 45
> - Perform at 00:45 (every hour)
> - Perform at minute 45 (hourly)

Is there a better way to express this?

EDIT: Another way may be "Perform hourly at :45 mins"

Comment: There may be a way but I don't know that it's very short... I'd usually say "hourly/every hour at ___ minutes after the hour" I feel like I've seen things that just say "recur hourly at ___ minutes". The thing about UI is that you can get away with being overly brief because it's usually obvious what you mean.

Comment: How does it look "Perform hourly at :42 mins"?

Comment: I wouldn't understand what "Generate hourly at :42 mins" means.  I would phrase it **"Run hourly at 42 minutes after the hour."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (00:45, 01:45, 02:45... 23:45) I would write:

> Perform hourly, at 45 minutes past the hour.

where "the hour" refers to the top of the hour (:00).